# VBA parse string into tokens

Tags: string, vba, parsing

I've got a string with a bunch of multi-letter codes in it and I'd like to parse it out according to those codes. I'm not sure how to make it look at more than one character to determine if it forms part of a code.

My string looks like this:

BBCTEEBOBBB

and I want to parse out these instances:

E
BB
CT
BOB

So the result should be output (or an array) that looks like this:

BB
CT
E
E
BOB
BB

Comment: When you say VBA, what specific product and version are you targeting? (VB6, Access 2007, Excel 2003, etc.)?

Comment: Is it possible that some codes will be subsets of others. That is, can there be a B code and a BB code? 

Also, is it possible that the sourc string will contain anything that is NOT one of the specified codes?

Comment: Nope. In this case I'm making quickie data entry dialog forms that populate a spreadsheet without my having to count cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use regular expressions.  In **Tools | References**, add the highest version of the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions library available on your PC (5.5 on mine).  Then you can use code such as the following:

```
Sub main()
  Dim x, m
  Set x = myparser("BBCTEEBOBBB")
  For Each m In x
    Debug.Print m.Value
  Next
End Sub

Function myparser(string_to_parse)
  Dim splitter As New RegExp
  splitter.Pattern = "E|BB|CT|BOB"
  splitter.Global = True
  Set myparser = splitter.Execute(string_to_parse)
End Function
```

The `myparser` function generates a `MatchCollection` object which can be toured as in the `main` subroutine.  The output is a list, in order, of all of the matches found in the input string.  You should be able to easily convert this to generate an array or space-delimited string.

Comment: Neat.  I wasn't aware of the inbuilt regexp library.

Comment: Freakin' awesome! I'm using this method to shortcut adding penalties to a spreadsheet for women's roller derby bouts. If you're ever in Lancaster, you've got free tickets.